# openFileOutput not working properly inside a singleton class - ideas/workarounds?

Tags: java, android

As a novice Android developer, I've faced a bit strange problem. I want to create a class, which methods other classes-activities-whatever could use for working with files in some special way. Let`s say for simplicity we would be logging some stuff. If I do following within an activity (in OnClick listener for example), everything works just fine:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("somefile", MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
osw.write("Very important foobar");
osw.flush();
osw.close();
```

But when I try to enclose that into some class and create singleton like that:

```
public class Logger extends BaseActivity {
//BaseActivity is the "init" class which extends Activity

public static final Logger INSTANCE = new Logger();
private Logger() { 
// singleton
}

public boolean doLog (String whatToLog) {
 try {
     FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("somefile", MODE_PRIVATE);
 OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
 osw.write(whatToLog);
 osw.flush();
 osw.close(); }
     catch (IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }  
     return true; }
```

and call it from other activity like that

```
Logger.INSTANCE.doLog("foobar");
```

app chrashes with NullPointerException (at line with openFileOutput). I suppose it`s because of improper use of singleton/activity here and now rewriting the code to run as a service. But maybe there are some better ideas to solve an issue? Or some workarounds?

Thanks for your contributions in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You based your singleton on an Activity that you didn't start as an Activity. Therefore, it doesn't have a valid Context, which is necessary for the IO calls. See Blundell's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538955/openfileoutput-not-working-properly-inside-a-singleton-class-ideas-workarounds/6539080#6539080) for better singleton, with one change: As per android.app.Application javadoc, your singleton should get the application context from the given context via Context.getApplicationContext(). See [why does AndroidTestCase.getContext().getApplicationContext() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6516441/424529) for another example.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your error doesn't come from the line you mention.

A null pointer exception happens in a statement of the form

```
A.B or A.B()
```

where A is null. And there is no such thing in your class at this line.

Please double check stack trace, send it and indicate line numbers.

Don't forget to save your files before all that.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: logs say it`s quite straightforward: 

06-30 17:13:43.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5250): java.lang.NullPointerException

06-30 17:13:43.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5250):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)

06-30 17:13:43.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5250):     at org.aclient.my.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:26)

06-30 17:13:43.614: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5250):     at org.aclient.my.AndroidClientMainActivity.onClick(AndroidClientMainActivity.java:79)

Comment: where line 26 is FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("somefile", MODE_PRIVATE);

and line 79 is Logger.INSTANCE.doLog("foobar");

Comment: though i have omited exception handling for shorter code, updated it

Answer (score 0):

You should write a singleton class like this:

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.Log;

 public final class SomeSingleton implements Cloneable {

private static final String TAG = "SomeSingleton";
private static SomeSingleton someSingleton ;
private static Context mContext;    

/**
 * I'm private because I'm a singleton, call getInstance()
 * @param context
 */
private SomeSingleton(){
      // Empty
}

public static synchronized SomeSingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(someSingleton == null){
        someSingleton = new SomeSingleton();
    }
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    return someSingleton;
}

public void playSomething(){
    // Do whatever
            mContext.openFileOutput("somefile", MODE_PRIVATE); // etc...
}

public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException("I'm a singleton!");
}
 }
```

Then you call it like this (depending on where you call it from):

```
 SomeSingleton.getInstance(context).playSomething();
 SomeSingleton.getInstance(this).playSomething();
 SomeSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).playSomething();
```

Edit: Note that this singleton works because it is not based on Activity and it gets a valid Context from whoever instantiates it (like another properly started Activity). Your original singleton failed because it never got started as an Activity, so it didn't have a valid Context. -cdhabecker

Comment: Dangerous as this singleton will be bound only to the first context requested.

Comment: @Dave Ah, got it. I was being to hasty :) Edited singleton.

Comment: thanks, it seems it makes sense, but   mContext = context   line cannot compile - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mContext - and to the  mContext.openFileOutput("somefile", MODE_PRIVATE); also (because we don`t have right context I suppose)

Comment: @Nick Ah sorry, just make the mContext class variable static. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Again I'm going to point out that this is dangerous.  Once you have bound this to an activity/context all subsequent calls to this will use that context. If you are ok with that kind of behavior, be my guest.  I don't feel that it is a good idea to do this this way.

Comment: @Dave no they won't dave. Everytime you call the singleton you call `SomeSingleton.getInstance(context).playSomething();` 
passing in the latest context you wish to use.

Comment: @Blundell still not thread safe, you have made it so that the instance you return is assigned the context and that context is used in the subsequent call.  You have synchronized the method that retrieves the context and that is fine but there is a gap between playSomething() call 1 and playSomething() call2 that could be executed by two different threads.  Just by putting short hand gI(ctx).playSomething() doesn't guarantee atomic execution.  What I'm pointing out here is that the context could change between those two points at which point you're going to deal with problems.

Comment: @Dave Ah I see I see, so the safety of the context is dependant on what your actually doing in the singleton. i.e. if the context really really matters. So your saying if I have a running service that calls playSomething() (with application context) and an activity that then call's playSomething() (with activity context) they could have the wrong context. I realise it needs to be accounted for but highly unlikely, good to know though.

Comment: I only use singleton calls from Activity's therefore, it's only possible to call it from one context at one time (unless you spawn a thread, but then this isn't a good place for a singleton anyway), I assume on bigger JavaEE systems this would be more of an issue with multiple windows and more multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

You're using your class properly I don't think that it is doing what you intend.  Your call to openFileOutput is failing because your singleton doesn't have a context. It will not have gone through the initialization life cycle phases and no context will have been established.

I would recommend that you create a service to allow for log writing and bind to that service in a "static" context on the objects you want to log with making sure that log requests are atomic.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to have a Singleton pattern that extended Activity? as the system gains access through onCreate etc

Comment: Thanks! Implementing service should work, I`m doing it right now. But I have not sorted it all out with code above. How do I pass the context to singleton?

Comment: @Blundel and @Nick I'm advocating against the "singleton" pattern here as there are much bigger things at work and I don't feel that the suggestions given are safe nor do I feel that they are the cleanest that could be offered.  This is my opinion and I welcome others.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `doLog` in OnCreate method, not in constructor of your Activity.
Before that, it doesn't have a context as @Dave G said.

Regards,
 stéphane