# Using static instead of parcelable/serialize -- is this bad?

Tags: android

I need to keep a reference to an object between different activities. The two said mentions seem to create new objects from activity to activity. This is a problem because changes to the object in the "child" activities don't persist once the parent activity gets focus. My solution to this was just to create a static getter in the parent-most activity which the child activities call and work with. Is this the incorrect way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share a single instance of an object between activities, you can create a singleton class. The only thing wrong with using your parent-most activity class to implement the singleton might be that it might violate the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your object persistent throughout the whole application lifecycle by making it a field in your `Application`-derived class.

```
public class MyAppication extends Application {

private Object mMyData; 

public setData(Object data) {
    mMyData = data;
}

public Object getData() {
      return mMyData;
}
```

}

Then `((MyApplication)getAppllication()).setData` or `getData()`

This way you can exchange data within the application because `MyApplication` will always exist.

You'll also have to add `MyApplcation` to manifest

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Singleton, this has a single instance whenever you talk to it. (Just like your describing).

Here's one I made earlier : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539080/413127

Comment: Why do you have a static reference to a Context. I can pass an activity to your singleton, then change the orientation, the activity gets destroyed but your context field holds it there. Moreover one might be able to use that context which is no longer valid

Comment: It's a private reference. The class is a singleton with one global context, it depends on your use of the context within the class if this becomes an issue.

Comment: The reference to the singleton would be destroyed along with the activity. Next time you ask for the singleton you are forced to update the context. Ah so it's not a 100% singleton I see what your saying.

Comment: The reference to the singleton is kept in a static field, so the reference would _not_ be destroyed along with the activity. Your code will leak an activity that is destroyed by an orientation change. One fix would be to store `context.getApplicationContext()` inside the singleton class.