# In android, why is a singleton never recycled?

Tags: android

I'm confused on this.  Just started android and have a long form that needs multiple activities to bring together an object.  I would like to pass the object from activity to activity to build it.  After reading the many posts and blogs and the Android Dev pages, it seems for non-persistent data, the best bet is to subclass application or create a singleton.  I reviewed this post [openFileOutput not working properly inside a singleton class - ideas/workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538955/openfileoutput-not-working-properly-inside-a-singleton-class-ideas-workarounds/6539080#6539080) and now my question is this, **Why doesn't a singleton ever get recycled?**  If we createSingleton() in Activity A, then move to Activity B and we are never passing a reference to the singleton, how does the garbage recycler know that we are going to come back to it again?  it seems to me that when Activity A is recycled and we have moved to Activity B that the singleton would die..

If we look at the following singleton..

```
public final class SomeSingleton implements Cloneable {

    private static final String TAG = "SomeSingleton";
    private static SomeSingleton someSingleton ;
    private static Context mContext;    

    /**
     * I'm private because I'm a singleton, call getInstance()
     * @param context
     */
    private SomeSingleton(){
        // Empty
    }

    public static synchronized SomeSingleton getInstance(Context context){
        if(someSingleton == null){
        someSingleton = new SomeSingleton();
        }
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    return someSingleton;
    }

    public void playSomething(){
        // Do whatever
        mContext.openFileOutput("somefile", MODE_PRIVATE); // etc...
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException("I'm a singleton!");
    }
}
```

And we create an instance of it through getInstance(), the class places a single instance of the class into static field, someSingleton.  Why is this instance never recycled?  If the answer is, "Static fields are never recycled?" What keeps us from using up all of our memory if we have many of them? Simple design considerations?  This seems risky if we are using lots of contributed libraries that we have no idea how many static fields are out there.  I just have this feeling that there is some fundamental rule that I am missing in OOP as a newb.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern is to put a reference to your singleton class in a static field. Static fields are not tied to a particular instance so they stick around until the JVM process is alive. It doesn't really matter how many activities access it. If you need to 'recycle' the singleton, maye you don't really need to use a singleton? Or provide an explicit `close()/open()` etc. methods.

Comment: thanks, I updated my original question to be more specific. I'm still a little confused.

Comment: In Java, and thus in Android, object only get garbage collected (GC) if there are no accessible references to them. Since static fields are always accessible if you stick something in a static field and never clear it (set to `null`) it won't be GC-ed. That's OK for a singleton though, since you generally want it to be accessible and not GC-ed. As for memory, there are lots of ways to exhaust it: just make list and start adding new objects to it in a loop. Eventually you will get an out of memory error and your process will be killed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that your Singleton's are not getting recycled is because activities in Android aren't destroyed when you think they are.

You pose a question like 'what happens when we move from activity A to B'. But when you do that in Android, Activity A is very rarely **destroyed**. It usually just goes into the [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) state. Thus, your Activity A will still be (mostly) intact if and when a user decided to hit the back button enough times to get back to activity A.