# Set a custom context in AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-contentprovider, android-context, android-testing

I'm trying to test my custom `ContentProvider` which only updates an item at a certain point in time.

In order to test the `shouldUpdate` branch, I need to revert time and set a custom date in my application. I couldn't stub out `System.currentTimeMillis()`, so I put a method in my Application object, and I'm trying to `setContext()` in `AndroidTestCase` like this.

```
private void setContextDate(final Date myCustomDate){
    final Context baseContext = getContext();
    final ContentResolver contentResolver = baseContext.getContentResolver();
    final MyApplication myApp = new MyApplication() {
        @Override
        public long currentTimeMillis(){
            return myCustomDate.getTime();
            // This normally returns System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        @Override
        public Context getBaseContext(){
            return baseContext;
        }
        @Override
        public ContentResolver getContentResolver(){
            return contentResolver;
        }
    };
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(baseContext) {
        @Override
        public Context getApplicationContext(){
            return myApp;
        }

    };
    setContext(contextWrapper);
```

}

However, when I call `getApplicationContext().currentTimeMillis()` in my provider, it returns the real implementation of the method, which is `System.currentTimeMillis()` and not my custom date time that I set in the `AndroidTestCase`.

What am I doing wrong?

p.s. I know about ProviderTestCase2, but I'm also accessing SharedPreferences in my provider, and for those ProviderTestCase2 returns null. That's why I'm using AndroidTestCase.

Comment: I have observed an apparent delay before AndroidTestCase sets up its underlying application context  (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6516441/424529). That delay could be causing AndroidTestCase to initialize its context after you set yours.

Comment: @cdhabecker I call `setContextDate()` in `setUp()` and after that I test that it returns the correct application context, which it does. Only when it runs the actual test does it return a different application context, which is not overridden.

Comment: It's changing the context between setup() and test()? Yuck. Seems like a different problem than I had. Good luck.