# Application context always returned null

Tags: android, android-context

I have this class in my project:

```
public class MyClass extends Application {

    // some stuff

    private Context context;

    public MyClass() {
        processContext();
        APP_DIRECTORY = context.getFilesDir();
        PRIVATE_FILE = new File(APP_DIRECTORY, MD5(getIEMI()));
    }


    public void processContext() {
        do {
            this.context = this.getApplicationContext();
        } while (this.context==null);
    }

    // some other stuff, such as reading or writing above declared files

    public String getIEMI() {
        String IMEI;
        Boolean hasTelephony = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
        if(hasTelephony) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        } else {
            IMEI = "IMEI_not_AVAIABLE";
        }
        return IMEI;
    }
}
```

But I get a NullPointerException (LogCat below) everywhere I call `context`, even if I tried to follow hints proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516441/why-does-androidtestcase-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-return-null) (a bug in the emulator).
I can't use `context = MyClass.this`, because I always (and only) get a NullPointerException.

> 04-14 20:25:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 04-14 20:25:28.063:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1084):   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
>   04-14 20:25:28.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):   at
>   com.example.mypackage.MyClass.processContext(MyClass.java:71) // this is the line of      APP_DIRECTORY = context.getFilesDir();

In fact, I'm not sure of having fully understood the definition of Context, in Android. I was quite confident that extending the class to the super `Application` class was sufficient.

I can't either construct the class with a parameter as the context, arriving from the caller (in such a way: `(new MyClass(MainActivity.this))`) because I have the need to read and write files even from classes which are not extensions of `Activity` class.

I'm getting mad, to tell the truth...

-- EDIT --

For a test purpose, I re-wrote the class, so that it is constructed in this way:

```
    public MyClass(Context app_context) {
        APP_CONTEXT = app_context;
        APP_DIRECTORY = APP_CONTEXT.getFilesDir();
    }
```

It always returns a NullPointerException when calling getFilesDir().

-- EDIT 2 --

As suggested in the comments, I added a declaration of onCreate():

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        APP_DIRECTORY = getFilesDir();
        LOGIN_FILE = new File(APP_DIRECTORY, name);

        Log.e("MyApp", "Main point reached.");
    }
```

And in this way everything looks good. But files declared in the onCreate() method seem always to be null, as if they are not declared at all: when I try to access to them, for reading or writing, I got a null pointer exception. And in fact "Main point reached." is never displayed, as if onCreate() is never called, nor processed, at all.

Comment: ok, you're trying to get the application context when the application is being constructed. have you tried in the `onCreate()`?

Comment: I will, if I can. MyClass is called by another, external. Are you saying that I have to construct even the external class with the Context of the which that is calling? Oh no, please. There's no way to get the context from Application class (extended by MyClass)?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

you can get the application context from de Application and from the Activity. You can only get the application context after the `onCreate()` of the activity. like this (put this in MyClass)
`@Override`
`public void onCreate(){super.onCreate(); getApplicationContext();}`

Comment: In fact, you were utterly right. Check the discussion just below...

Comment: * after the `onCreate()` of the **Application**. My mistake.

Comment: I edited the question, including the results of your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Application is Context. Try not to use constructor, but onCreate instead.

You may call `getFilesDir` directly without having `private Context context;`.

Comment: APP_DIRECTORY = getFilesDir();

generates the "null error", alas!, as does this one:

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        context = MyClass.this;
    }

Comment: don't forget to call the `super.OnCreate()` before accessing the context

Comment: @Gianluca no need to assign this to context. Just use this directly.

Comment: GREAT! It definitely works! But, I don't know why, declaring those file variables in the onCreate() method still generates an error while trying to access to them: if(LOGIN_FILE.exists()) -> java.lang.NullPointerException. Maybe it's due to getIMEI(), which doesn't work properly...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.context` with `getActivity()`