# getApplicationContext() returns null when called from J Unit Test Case

Tags: android, junit, android-service

I have to do J Unit Testing of Android Class that extend to Service.

I have following lines in my Source code :-

```
    public class AService extends Service{

        public AService () {
            super("AService");
        }
    ....
    ...
    @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(
                BroadCastReceiver_Object,
                new IntentFilter("any String"));
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
        }
...
...
}
```

I need to do J Unit Testing of above class. I wrote Test Class as follows :-

```
public class AServiceTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    AService AServiceobj;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see junit.framework.TestCase#setUp()
     */
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        AServiceobj = new AService();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see junit.framework.TestCase#tearDown()
     */
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }


    public void testonStart() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        int startId = 0;
        AServiceobj.onStart(intent, startId);
    }
}
```

**But the above TC fail and it gives Null Pointer Exception at "getApplicationContext()".**
How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try using getContext() instead of getApplicationContext()?

Comment: getContext() is not defined for Service.

Comment: Have you seen this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8308065/1239966

Comment: I have checked stackoverflow.com/a/8308065/1239966 but in that it was not mentioned clearly how to fix it. I did not get that answer.

Comment: can you use Constructor to pass Context?

Answer (score 1):

For testing service you can extend `ServiceTestCase` instead.

You can then also use `setApplication()` or/and `setContext()` to use with your mock context before you start service.

See this article for more info http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/service_testing.html

**Update**: i added short example how to use ServiceTestCase.

MyService is just simple service which reads processName from application context (so app context must be there. This is just to confirm that example works, otherwise there would be the same problem as in your case NullPointerException).

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    private String procName;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();

        procName = ctx.getApplicationInfo().processName;
    }

    public String getProcName(){
        return this.procName;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new LocalBinder();
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is test for service:

```
public class MyServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<MyService> {

    public MyServiceTest() {
        super(MyService.class);
    }

    public void testProcName(){
        // here we take and use context from ServiceTestCase.getContext()
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
        startService(intent);

        assertNotNull(getService().getProcName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that it is also giving same exception.

Comment: I don't know how you used ServiceTestCase so I updated post with example that works. Hope it helps.

Comment: I also tried using ServiceTestCase it's working fine. 'Android User', upload your code, so that we can have a look on it.